# Solving Lotka-Volterra Equations by Python

Tags: python, matlab, ode

I am trying to translate a paragraph of MATLAB code into Python3 code.

The code is about Lotka-Volterra Equations

Here is the original code by MATLAB

```matlab
t0=0; tf=6*pi; eps=0.1; delta=0;
r=[1/2, 1, 2];
options = odeset(’RelTol’,1e-6,’AbsTol’,1.e-9);

%phase space plot
xpos=[2.5 2.5 2.5]; ypos=[3.5 3.5 3.5]
for i=1:length(r);
    for eps=0.1:0.1:1.0;
       [t,UV]=ode45(@(t,UV) lv_eq(t,UV,r(i)),[t0,tf],[1+eps 1+delta],options);
        U=UV(:,1); V=UV(:,2);
    figure(2);subplot(1,3,i); plot(U,V); hold on;
    end
    axis equal; axis([0 4 0 4]);
    text(xpos(i),ypos(i),[’r=’,num2str(r(i))]);
    if i==1; ylabel(’predator’); end;
    xlabel(’prey’);
end

function dUV=lv_eq(t,UV,r)
dUV=zeros(2,1);
dUV(1) = r*(UV(1)-UV(1)*UV(2));
dUV(2) = (1/r)*(UV(1)*UV(2)-UV(2));
```

The following is my code by Python3:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
from functools import partial

def lotka_volterra(t, X, r):
    return np.array([r*(X[0]-X[0]*X[1]), (1/r)*(X[0]*X[1]-X[1])])


t0=0
tf=6*np.pi
prey_0 = 0.1
predator_0 = 0
rs = [0.5, 1, 2]


fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, sharey=True)
for i in range(len(rs)):
    for prey_0 in np.arange(0.1, 1.0, 0.1):
        f = partial(lotka_volterra, r=rs[i])
        sol = integrate.solve_ivp(f, t_span=[t0, tf], y0=[1+prey_0, 1+predator_0], rtol=1e-6, atol=1.e-9)
        U, V = sol.y
        axes[i].plot(U, V)

    axes[i].axis([0, 4, 0, 4])
    axes[i].set_title('r='+str(rs[i]))
    axes[i].set_xlabel('prey')
    if i==0:
        axes[i].set_ylabel('predator')
```

The original code's outputs are:

[image: MATLAB outputs]

My code's outputs are:

[image: Python outputs]

I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you are defining the inputs to `lotka_volterra` in the wrong order. Shouldn't the first be `t` ?

Comment: Thank you very much, friend. I have corrected this error. However, I come across a new problem with the outputs, so I re-edited the original question. Thanks again!

Comment: Both Matlab and python outputs are the same on `MATLAB_R2019a`

Comment: You could add the option `figsize=(3*5,5)` to the `subplots` commands. You get a plot closer to the first one if you initialize on the diagonal, `UV0 = [ 1+eps  1+eps ]`. The diagonal looks like the only direction where the curves are equally spaced.

Comment: @Adam Thanks, friend, I will give it a try.